# Symfony2 Security Configuration - How to use two firewalls side by side

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication

I want to use a symfony2 application with 2 firewalls: one with users from database for the frontend, and another with in memory users for the backend.

I have read through all the documentations and various stackoverflow questions, but I cannot solve my problem.

This is my **security.yml** configuration so far:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        frontend:
            pattern:    ^/
            provider: fe_users
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                username_parameter: _email
                login_path:  _login
                check_path:  _login_check
                remember_me: true
                default_target_path: _profile
                #always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
            remember_me:
                key: MiPassphrase
                lifetime: 1800
                path: /.*
                domain: ~
        backend:
            pattern:   ^/backend
            provider: be_users
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:
                realm: ""

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/backend$, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    encoders:
        vv\xx\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    providers:
        fe_users:
            entity: { class: vvxx:User, property: email }
        be_users:
            memory:
                users:
                    d: { password: c, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
```

What happens with that:

The frontend authentication works fine. If user is not logged in to frontend, the visit of /backend redirects me to /login. If user IS logged in (and authenticated) to frontend, the visit of /backend gives me a 403 access denied. A "classic" http authentication loginform never appears.

Can anybody have a look at my configuration and figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Have you tried using same `context` in each firewall? e.g `context: my_project` in both firewalls

Comment: Try inversing firewall order, place backend before frontend

Comment: Yeah like @IgorPantović says, all of your routes are being caught by the `^/` pattern so switching them around should do it for you.

Comment: nice, that did the trick! thanks a lot guys!
i thought that rule only is important for access_control, didnt know it is for firewall as well.

anyone want to post a answer so that i can accept it?

Comment: it works now in localhost, but http authentication completely fails on server - no input shows up, route is accessible :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firewalls are matched on a first match basis. Your least restrictive patterns should come after more restrictive ones in your firewall list. Currently your `frontend` pattern is matching everything so your `backend` pattern is never being checked.

As Igor Pantovic suggests:

> Try inversing firewall order, place backend before frontend